# How to scroll to a particular record in grid?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Previously, I used `persistent` grid plugin, until I found out that it caused some terrible slowdown - about 3-4 extra seconds of grid rendering (~20 columns and 300 rows). So, I do not want all this plugin functionality, the only thing I want to have is scrolling to a selected record in grid (there may be a lot of records selected, so scrolling to the first one is enough). I try to do it like this:

```
.... a lot of code ...
rowIndex=grid.store.indexOf(grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0]);
record=grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
grid.store.remove(record); // <- I remove it, because its content has changed
grid.store.insert(rowIndex,Ext.create('GridModel',json.items[0]));  // <- I insert 
// it back with new values
grid.getSelectionModel().select(  rowIndex  ); // <- This works, I see a checkmark
grid.getView().focusRow( record ); // <- This is not working
....
```

Instead of what I expect to see, I see scrolling to the top of the grid.

**EDIT**

This is not working:

```
Ext.fly(grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex)).scrollIntoView(); // instead of focus
```

Also not working:

```
var rowEl=grid.getView().getNode(rowIndex);
rowEl.scrollIntoView(grid.el, false);
```

So, what to use instead of focus?

**EDIT**

Setting `deferRowRender` to false in grid config also has no effect. Still, grid scroll to the very top of its view.

**EDIT**

Well, as it turned out, `focusRow` had no effect because of the `grid.store.sync` call. So, I put this routine inside `sync` callback function and now it is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In extjs 4 the solution might be use method **scrollBy()** http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-scrollBy

In Extjs 5: try the methods **getScrollable()**.**scrollTo(...)**;
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html#placeholder-accessor-getScrollable
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html#method-scrollTo

In Extjs 6: try the methods **getScrollable()**.**scrollToRecord(...)**;
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#method-getScrollable
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.grid.Grid.html#method-scrollToRecord

Although on a different issue, this post may be useful: [How to scroll to the end of the form in ExtJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672250/how-to-scroll-to-the-end-of-the-form-in-extjs/40674956#40674956)

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
grid.getView().focusRow( record );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When posting code, please try to include a short explanation, so that the OP can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var numIndex=** //this is record  index
var x=grid.getView().getScrollX();
grid.getView().scrollTo(x,numIndex*21); //x,y --> unit is pixel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When posting code, please try to include a short explanation so that the OP can understand it.